# Is there an equivalent scripting approach in .NET similar to scripting.dev.java.net for Java?

Tags: javascript, .net, ruby

In Java, it is possible to interpret various scripting languages dynamically from within the JVM at runtime. This makes it possible to dynamically evaluate Ruby, Javascript, Scala, and other code without recompiling. (https://scripting.dev.java.net/)

Is it possible to do something similar in the .Net environment that would be deployable to Azure? If so, what languages are best supported?

Comment: Related'ish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067784/c-net-scripting-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the simplest way to do that would be to use Node.js in Windows Azure. It does not leverage .NET, but it is a good way to run JavaScript on the server side. Windows Azure can run Node.js in Windows Azure Web Sites for example. More information at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/